# Python ftplib error

Tags: python, ftp

I have a python program which basically just moves files around between remote FTP server and local machine. I have a bit of code to delete a file on the FTP site, similar to

```
try:
    ftplib_obj.delete(some_file)
except ftplib.error_perm, e:
    print str(e)
    raise
```

I'm getting a "550: Delete operation failed", and I have no idea why. The most baffling thing is that I can log in manually, with the same credentials, and delete the file no problem. Any idea what the issue could be, or at least, is there a way I can get a more descriptive error message?

NOTE: I've gone through some possible causes of this error, such as file not existing or permission denied, but none of these apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can do couple of things:

1. Set debug level (using ftplib_obj.set_debuglevel(9)), this might give some insights into the issue.
2. Run the FTP command you run in interactive mode using the function

   ```
   ftplib_obj.voidcmd('DEL *filename*')
   ```